# Select values of rows across dataframes using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one is populated with barcodes and their product's prices across several supermarkets during the COVID pandemic, and the other one contains the actual product names and their barcodes along with a few category_id's etc, which are known (so I know which category_id to target in order to get a specific set of barcodes.)

the df_markets:

```
             BARCODE          AC    BFRESH  LIDL    SUPERM  
Date                            
2020-01-03  5201263086618   6.36    7.97    0   0   8.31             
2020-01-03  5201263086625   7.58    9.53    0   0   9.91    
2020-01-03  7322540574852   18.11   18.34   0   0   8.86    
2020-01-03  7322540647136   18.8    18.95   0   0   18.9    
2020-01-03  7322540587555   18.22   18.98   0   0   9.21
```

and the df_bar:

```
    product_id  category_id   subcategory_name    BARCODE           name        
0   1.0             37.0       Adult diapers     5.201263e+12   Sani Pants N2 Medium 14 
1   2.0             37.0       Adult diapers     5.201263e+12   Sani Pants N3 Large 14  
2   3.0             37.0       Adult diapers     7.322541e+12   Tena Pants Plus Large 
3   4.0             37.0       Adult diapers     7.322541e+12   Tena Slip Super Large N4 
4   5.0             37.0       Adult diapers     7.322541e+12   Tena Pants Plus Extra Large
```

What I've tried doing is first locate inside the df_bar all of the barcodes that have a category_id of 114.0 (which is of detergent) like that:

```
df_bar.loc[df_bar['category_id']==114.0]
```

and that produced a two-rows dataframe, so I know that this category_id exists, and then tried locating inside the df_markets dataframe all of the barcodes that much this search query:

```
df_markets.loc[df_markets['BARCODE'].isin(df_bar.loc[df_bar['category_id']==114.0])]
```

like that, but that produces an empty dataframe like that:

```
       BARCODE  AC  BFRESH  LIDL    SUPERM  
Date
```

so I am guessing the problem is that the df_markets has the barcodes in this format "*5201263086618*" while the df_bar has the barcodes in this format "*5.201263e+12*". Do you know what needs to be done to be able to search within the df_markets dataframe effectively?
Or let me know if there's something wrong with my code.

---

A minor edit that helped me after Danila's suggestion was to turn my "query" into this :

```
df_bar['BARCODE'] = df_bar['BARCODE'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:-2])
#above line changed the format
df_markets.loc[df_markets['BARCODE'].isin(df_bar.loc[df_bar['category_id']==114.0]['BARCODE'])]
```

so that it can take into consideration **only** the BARCODE column.

Comment: just convert `BARCODE` column to string. example: `df_bar['BARCODE'] = df_bar['BARCODE'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:-2])`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar that fixed my problem with the barcode's format! So if you want to make it an answer I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just convert BARCODE column to string. example:

```
 df_bar['BARCODE'] = df_bar['BARCODE'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:-2])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try going for a parse!

```
file = pandas.read_excel("your_file.xlsx", 0) #  is the sheet index
for col, row in file.iterrows():
    if row.get('category_id') == 114.0:
        # do something
```

Note that this solution may not be optimized for a big dataframe, since it has to parse the entire dataset until it finds what you need

Answer (score -1):

Convert Barcode to similar format.

```
df_bar['BARCODE'] = int(float(df_bar['BARCODE']))
```

Comment: that won't work. because `df_bar['BARCODE']` is a series. so in this case you'll get a `TypeError` or whatever.

Comment: would it work if i take each data and convert it using float?

Answer (score -2):

Provided that the `df_bar['BARCODE']` is a number in scientific notation, you can use the following command before loading your dataset:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)
```